# Item versi in laude Christi editi a juvenco presbytero. can[untur] quando reversi fuerint et appropinquant regias ecclesie (sic)

Tags: medieval-latin

This is a rubric for the hymn Gloria, laus, et honor from an 11th century manuscript.  I've asked several people for help on it.  Some said it is partly in Italian.  I'm not sure why the (sic) is added there.  This is about the best I could do:
Verses in praise of Christ made available by a young priest. The verses are sung when they have returned and are approaching the direction of the church. I would like a literal translation, if possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a literal translation:

> Likewise, the verses composed in praise of Christ by the Presbyter [Juvencus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juvencus). They are sung when they have returned and are approaching the main doors of the church.

- "Item" probably refers to whatever preceded, i.e. "in the same way as before."
- "Versi" seems to be the plural of "versus, -ūs" interpreted as 2nd declension. I don't know if this was a common medieval usage, but I've seen it done for other 4th declension words.
- *Regiae* appear to be the main doors of a church, based on a few matches I found in other medieval texts.

Regarding Juvencus, it appears that this is an erroneous attribution. [*Paléographie musicale*, pg. 249](https://archive.org/details/palographiemusic14macq/page/248) indicates the following:

> On notera ... que deux de nos manuscrits, les Graduels VI. 34 et VI. 38 de Bénévent désignent, comme auteur du *Gloria laus*, non pas Théodulphe, mais Juvencus. Cette attribution est insoutenable.

The footnote goes on to mention two possible reasons: (1) the authors were noted for their similar style by earlier writers, and (2) their works may have been grouped together in the same manuscript.

Comment: Great.  Thanks a lot.  juvenco bothers me.  It's not capitalized and those verses are written by Theodulf of Orleans.  Could it mean something else?

Comment: @R.B.Jawad I added some further information--that's what the text says, but it appears to be an error.

Comment: Interesting.  Ok, that is what the [sic] is for, then.  Thanks a lot.